# 'Home' menu item in Joomla displays an empty drop down? Alternatively, how do I even create a new 'Home' menu item that links to the home page?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Joomla is very frustrating. It seems so complicated to do either of the following:

1. Remove the drop down behavior of the 'Home' menu item in my nav bar is creating. It is just an empty drop down when all I want it to do is just be a simple link that goes back to the home page.[image: Screenshot of 'Home' empty drop down menu]
2. Say I remove the 'Home' menu item and create a new one, it gives no options in the menu manager to set this up as it only gives me options to link to articles? I have done some research and people say to link it as an external/internal URL however i keep getting an error saying the menu item must be a component.

At the moment, my 'Home' menu item is linking to Featured Articles which displays my home page.

Anyone know how to fix this simple issue?

Here are some more screenshots of the backend:
[image: screenshot of menu item list]
[image: screenshot of menu item]

Comment: The question doesn't show research but since the problem is with the menu i suggest you show the screen shots of your menu items view for this menu and also the settings in your menu module.

Comment: Can you let us know what module you use for display menu ? by default joomla doesn't create dropdown menu if you don't have child element, and also you need to select this option in module menu. Maybe you can also give a link to your website so we can check ? Aslo like Elin said, have you try something ?